# Is there a way to use iCloud KeyValue Storage in public container?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, key-value-store

I know I can use CloudKit publicDatabase and create a records shared between all users of my app. But I actually need the sama public database, but for KeyValueStorage. Something like public UserDefaults in iCloud. Is it possible?

My store is initialized like this:

```
let keyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default
```

but this is only for current user container, not publc.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` and CloudKit databases are completely unrelated. (Besides the fact, they are both cloud storage. :-)

If you need something like `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` in the public CloudKit database, you need to *simulate* this by yourself. For example by serialising the dictionary into a single Data object and store this object or have a record type (key, value) which is filled accordingly.